# How to get geom_boxplot to apply y-limits before calculating boxes?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is a boxplot:

```
qplot(cyl, mpg, data=mtcars) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_y_continuous()
```

that looks like this:
[image]

Now I add limits to the y axis:

```
qplot(cyl, mpg, data=mtcars) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,20))
```

and the whole picture changes:

[image]

How do I get the same picture as the first, just with a 'viewport' showing y=0 to 20?

And .. what is the second picture?  It looks like there is actually data missing (example: 3-4 points for cyl=4).

Comment: There aren't any observations with `cyl = 4` that have `mpg < 20` apparently.

Comment: @joran: on the top graph, there appear to be 3-4 black dots.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From joran's comment, this works:

```
qplot(cyl, mpg, data=mtcars) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,20))
```

From [the docs](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/coord_cartesian.html):

> There are two ways of zooming the plot display: with scales or  with
>   coordinate systems.  They work in two rather different ways.
>
> Setting the limits on a scale will throw away all data that's not 
>   inside these limits.  This is equivalent to plotting a subset of  the
>   original data
>
> Setting the limits on the coordinate system performs a visual zoom 
>   the data is unchanged, and we just view a small portion of the
>   original  plot.

Thanks joran!

Comment: You might also find it helpful to use `factor(cyl)` rather than just `cyl`.